# Azure Mobile Services - Passing arrays through Custom Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services with a C# client. I have a table of "Scores" that have a Facebook Id for each score. What I need to do is pass in an array of friends for a user and return all scores in that list of friends.

So I tried this on the client:

```
        return _client.GetTable<Score>().WithParameters(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Level", level.ToString() },
            //aggregate our string[] to a comma-delimited string
            { "Friends", friends.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (b, s) => b.Append(s).Append(',')).ToString() }

        }).ToListAsync();
```

Which is weird I only have the option to pass in strings for custom parameters.

So I did this on the server's read:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    query.where({ Level: request.parameters.Level, UserId: request.parameters.Friends.split(',') });

    request.execute();
}
```

It doesn't seem like a comma-delimited list is going to work. I get this error on the server:

```
Error in script '/table/Score.read.js'. Error: Unsupported literal value chucknorris,bobloblaw,
```

NOTE: I passed `chucknorris` and `bobloblaw` as Facebook ids for a test.

Is there another way to make this work? The "Level" value filters just fine if I take out the string delimited stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the `mssql` object definitely works, but you can also use a function in the `query.where` call, with the function returning the condition you want:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    query.where(function(level, userIds) {
        return this.Level === level && this.UserId in userIds; 
    }, request.parameters.Level, request.parameters.Friends.split(','));

    request.execute();
}
```

Notice that the `in` operator in this function doesn't behave quite exactly like the `in` operator in JavaScript. Instead, it's used exactly to have an 'or' grouping of equality statements, which you were creating "by hand" to pass to the SQL object.

Comment: I'll try this on Monday, this seems better than raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with this server-side script:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    var innerSql = '';
    var friends = request.parameters.Friends.split(',');
    var parameters = new Array(friends.length + 1);
    parameters[0] = request.parameters.Level;

    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (i !== 0) {
            innerSql += ' or ';
        }
        innerSql += 'UserId = ?';

        parameters[i + 1] = friends[i];
    }

    mssql.query('select * from Score where Level=? and (' + innerSql + ')', parameters, {
        success: function (results) {
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
        }
    });

}
```

I'll keep this answer open for a few days if someone has a cleaner solution.